# Can't print HTML emails on Letter pages correctly

Tags: printing, html, microsoft-outlook-2003

We have this ¿"*(_&"/*! problem since few weeks in our office. I would say almost since we've upgraded to IE8.

When a user want to print a HTML email with tables or any other HTML (Pictures, tables...) stuff in it, the email is not printed correctly on Letter pages (8½x11). The whole email seems to be bigger than the 8½x11 page itself. It's not scaled correctly...

- I've uncheck the "shrink to fit"
  feature. No luck
- I've set margins
  correctly (Print fine with non-html
  emails) I've set the font size (View
- Text size) as smallest, no luck still...

So right now I'm clueless.

Any takers on this one?

Thanks a bunch!

David.

Comment: I see that you tried setting the margins, but did you try setting all of the margins to zero?  When you enter them as zero, they will usually default to something slightly higher, but regardless I've seen this trick work on occasion.

Comment: I try it now!... not now! She's AFK

Comment: Why are you printing e-mail?  Tsk tsk, that's naughty.

Comment: @boot13: It's not working. I can't set margins to 0. It's 0.18 for up/down and 0.something for sides. The email is still not printed correctly.

Comment: @Joel: The lawyers need to have the Expedia.ca printed information. His legal assistant tried to print it but it's not printing correctly as described below.

Comment: Silly lawyers.  Print to PDF and give 'em a Kindle to view the files.  It'll pay for itself in no time.

Comment: Not a bad idea for the PDF print out.

Comment: @r0ca: How much of the page is missing?  Just a ballpark percentage, I mean; for instance: 20% right side, 30% bottom.  Something like that.

Comment: I would say like 35-40% is missing on the left. It's fine on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. I had to disable the "Shrink to fit" feature... Or enable it in some cases.